# Excel: Retrieve data from within a specific html tag on a website and insert that data into an Excel worksheet

Tags: html, excel, domdocument, dhtml

I was looking at the web queries in excel and how you can retrieve data from a html table in a website quite easily. I wish to get a single string from within a html tag:

```
 <span class="linePrice">I WANT THIS DATA<!----></span>
```

Is this possible? If it is, how? A vbn solution would also be useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can get that information from the **DHTML DOM Document**

see these links:

- [MSDN Library - DOM Document Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [MSDN Library - getElementById Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)